# JQuery hide/show gone wrong

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is a simplified example of what i'm working with, working around preexisting code:

Basically I have 2 divs I want to hide/show in multiple places(stage 1, stage 2, stage 3,etc), as so:

```
var blue_div = "#Blue";
var red_div = "#Red";
var blue_stage = "#Blue" + count;
var red_stage = "#Red" + count;
```

*Adding insult to injury* the div's exist elsewhere on page and are hidden. Need to pull the content into another div for each stage. So i'm using .prepend() to grab the content, as so:

```
var blue_html = $(blue_div).html();
var new_div = "#new_div";

$(new_div).prepend(blue_html);
$(new_div).attr('id', blue_stage); //Changing the id based on the stage
```

**That last part is really whats throwing me**...As now I'm trying to use the new_div without first ending the script so it's not yet in the DOM...

```
if ($(blue_stage).is(':hidden')) {
    $(blue_stage).show()
    $("#cancel").bind("click",function(){
        $(blue_stage).hide()
    }
}
```

I've seen a lot done with *Window setTimeout()* as well as *setinterval* and *.queue()*. But my attempts have all failed. Hopefully my example wasn't confusing, any help at all is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do something like this:

```
var $new_div = $('<div id="' + blue_stage + '"></div>');
```

which will allow you to edit the element directly so you can do things like:

```
$new_div.prepend(blue_html);
```

to change the id you do:

```
$new_div.attr('id', blue_stage)
```

and note when your setting the id like this you don't need the "#" as the other answer mentions

Answer (score 1):

Remember that you use the hash-mark `#` when selecting, but when setting as an ID on a node, you just use the identifier without this mark. So this line:

```
$(new_div).attr('id', blue_stage); //Changing the id based on the stage
```

Equates to this:

```
$(new_div).attr('id', '#Blue' + count);
```

But should perhaps be like this:

```
$(new_div).attr('id', 'Blue' + count);
```

(without the hashmark).

Hopefully your problem is as easily solved!  Good luck!